# Deleting first few rows and change the header names to row values

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has column names assigned by R.

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
NA     NA     ABC
NA     NA     XYZ
Name1  Name2  Name3
Joe    Paul   Ross
```

I want to delete the first 3 rows including the Col Numbers header assigned by R, and Make Name1, Name2, Name 3 the header names of the columns in the dataframe.

to delete the rows, I was trying to do tail(df,-3).. But it's not removing Col Number rows, and deleting my Name row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
names(df) <- df[3,]
```

then

```
df <- df[-c(1:3),]

df
  Name1 Name2 Name3
4   Joe  Paul  Ross
```

Comment: When i tried the names code, I got the error below- 'names' attribute [440] must be the same length as the vector [40]

Comment: Try it again - you might have a previous version where I got my comma in the wrong place.  I thought I had edited it out quickly enough!